# Yii2 Select2 and related tables

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have two related tables. For example,

tbl_one 
id
name

tbl_second
id
id_tblone(this is fk)
name

For example:

tbl_one 
id: 1
name: input one

tbl_second
id: 1
id_tblone: 1
name: data one
id: 2
id_tblone: 1
name: data two

Select will show: 
input one
input two

I want to use Kartik's select in a form that will save new data in tbl_second. So I need Select2 to select id_tblone (or id from tbl_one) and his according name. User needs to select, let's say proper category (from first table - I have fk that relates those two tables) and add some new data under that category in second table.
What would be proper way to do this?

Edit: i have managed so far to show proper names under proper id_tblone, but it saves data with value null in id_tblone column in my second table

In controller:

```
 $query = array();
    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())

               ->select(['id', 'name'])

               ->from('tbl_one')

               ->leftJoin('tbl_second', 'tbl_second.id_tblone = tbl_one.id')

               ->all();
```

in view:

```
 $data = ArrayHelper::map($query,'name', 'id');
 echo Select2::widget([ 
                'name' => 'newname',
                'data' => $data,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]);
```